# How to sort an array depending on the other array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi i have 2 arrays and both have same values but in different order, i want to sort 1 array depending on the other can you help me on how to do this.

Code :

1 array is say `string[] abc = [];` and other array that is items which is shown below in the code. As i said both have same number of values

```
return new PdfGenerationRequest
            {
                Email = userEmail,
                FileName = zipName,
                AppName = appName,
                Period = period,
                Year = year,
                Quarter = quarter,
                TemplateTypeId = templateTypeId,
                WPGroup = wpGroup,
                MyDealsOnly = myDealsOnly,
                Watermark = watermark,
                Items = items.OrderBy(x => x.FileName).ToArray()
            };
```

Currently i am sorting in asc order based on items array.
Please suggest me on how to sort the items array based on the abc array.

so for ex :

Abc has 3 elements that is Apple, Cat, Bat

and items has 3 elements that is cat, bat, apple

but here i want to sort it based on ABC the items array should be ordered. So here the end result from items should be Apple, Cat, Bat

Comment: i am not i understand the problem.  can you add the code that you have tried

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro i have added an example to this. I am actually new to this, Hope this example helps you

Comment: me too, i dont understand what you want..

Comment: I don't see how that code you included has anything to do with the question. Are you talking about a specific property? Which one?

Comment: The code you have looks like an anonymous inner class, but you are talking about an array

Comment: if you have the same elements, but just a different order and want the order of the first array, why not just return the first array?

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is slightly confusing, and it's not completely clear if you're looking for a case-insensitive comparison or not, but going off of this statement:

> *"`abc` has 3 elements: `{"Apple", "Cat", "Bat"}` and `items` has 3 elements that is `{"cat", "bat", "apple"}` [and] I want to sort it based on `abc`*

The way to compare one to another is to use the `index` of the item in the first array for sorting the second array, which we can do by using the `Array.IndexOf` method. For example:

```
var abc = new [] {"Apple", "Cat", "Bat"};
var items = new[] {"Cat", "Bat", "Apple"};

items = items
    .OrderBy(item => 
        abc.Contains(item) ? Array.IndexOf(abc, item) : int.MaxValue)
    .ToArray();

// Now items = {"Apple", "Cat", "Bat"}
```

Note that we're using the ternary operator `?:` to return `int.MaxValue` if `Contains` returns `false`, which will put any items that aren't in `abc` at the end of the sort order.

---

But in your example you showed that `items` actually contained *lower-case* versions of the strings in `abc`. If this is the case and you want to match them with a case-insensitive comparison, one way to get the index is to use the `System.Linq` extention method `Select` to get both the item and it's index from `abc`, then find the `FirstOrDefault` item that matches the current item in `items` using a case-insensitive comparison:

```
var abc = new [] {"Apple", "Cat", "Bat"};
var items = new[] {"cat", "bat", "apple"};

items = items.OrderBy(i => abc.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
    .FirstOrDefault(a => 
        i.Equals(a.item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.index ?? int.MaxValue)
    .ToArray();

// Now items = {"apple", "cat", "bat"}
```

Note that because `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if the item doesn't exist, we're using the `?.` and `??` operators to once again return `int.MaxValue` if that happens to put any items that aren't in `abc` at the end of the sort order.